# Calculating $\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dt \exp \left[-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x - vt}{\sigma}\right)^2\right] e^{i \omega t}$

Tags: integration

Calculate:
$$\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dt \exp \left[-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x - vt}{\sigma}\right)^2\right] e^{i \omega t}.$$

Apparently in the problem, this evaluates to another gaussian with width $\sigma_{\omega}$ however I'm slightly skeptical of this. Can anyone show the workings?

Comment: Apparently the first exponential is independent of $\;\omega\;$ ...? That'd be weird.

Comment: Integration is with respect to $\omega$?

Comment: Isn't there any Dirac delta function in the integrand that you probably have missed?

Comment: oh oops, sorry about that guys! I meant for the integral to be differentiated with $dt$ instead of $d\omega$.

Comment: Change the title as well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you know the standard fact that $\frac1  {\sqrt {2\pi}} \int_{-\infty} ^{\infty} e^{isz} e^{-z^{2}/2}dz=e^{-s^{2}/2}$? If you know this you only have to make the substitution $z=\frac {vt-x} {\sigma}$ to get the value of the integral as $\frac {\sigma} {\sqrt {2\pi}} e^{i\omega x /v} e^{-\omega^{2}\sigma^{2}/v^{2}}$.

[See the 9th entry in the table in this article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution ].

Comment: Thanks a lot! Sorry that this question was so standard, I'll try to do more research next time when I ask a question here.