# Show $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp \left\{- \frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2} \right\} \, dx = \sigma$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

\begin{align*}
  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp \left\{- \frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2} \right\} \, dx &= \sigma \\
\end{align*}

I can verify that that is correct. Is there a relatively simple way to demonstrate this integral?

I see many other questions addressing similar integrals, but I'd like to see how to do this particular integral.

Comment: Which "similar" integrals have you seen? In particular, by scaling it is likely you could reduce to one of those integrals.

Comment: this one is close, but really not quite the same: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/370518/evaluating-int-mathbbr-frac-exp-x21x2-mathrmdx

Comment: here's another that is close but more complicated: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3793382/calculating-frac12-pi-int-infty-infty-dt-exp-left-frac12-l

Comment: Take the result from $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2} dx$ and use a substitution to get that result.

Comment: Have you seen the computation for $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}dx$? (Usually done by polar coordinates) The problem you have reduces to this by a change of variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [Gaussian integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/154968/is-there-really-no-way-to-integrate-e-x2):

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}dx=\sqrt{\pi}$$ and then substituting $x=\sqrt{2}\sigma u$, so $dx=\sqrt{2}\sigma du$ we have

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}}dx=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-u^2}\sqrt{2}\sigma du$$
$$=\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-u^2}du=\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{\pi}}\sqrt{\pi}=\sigma.$$

(Note in this case $\sigma>0,$ but if $\sigma<0$, then the result should be $-\sigma.$ Thus is general the result is $|\sigma|.$)

Answer (score 1):

Let $A = (\int_{- \infty}^{\infty} \text{exp}(-x^{2})dx)^{2} = \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} \text{exp}(-x^{2})dx \cdot \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} \text{exp}(-y^{2}) dy = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{- \infty}^{\infty} \text{exp}(-x^{2}-y^{2})dxdy$

$  \  \  $

Take $x = rcos(t), y = rsen(t)$, with $0<r< \infty$, $0≤t<2π$ (thus $x² + y² = r²$)

Then

$   \   \  $

$A = \int_{0}^{2π}\int_{0}^{\infty} r\cdot \text{exp}(-r²) dr dt $

$ \  \ $

We have that $\int r \cdot \text{exp}(-r²) dr = -\frac{ \text{exp}(-r²)}{2}$

Then $\int_{0}^{\infty} r \cdot \text{exp}(-r²) dr = -\frac{ \text{exp}(-\infty)}{2} + \frac{ \text{exp}(0)}{2}  = \frac{1}{2}$

$  \  \  $

Thus $A = \int_{0}^{2π} \frac{1}{2} dt = π$

$ \  \ $

So $\sqrt{π} = \sqrt{A} = \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} \text{exp}(-x^{2})$

$ \  \   $

Now, go to the original problem..

$ \  \ $

$B = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \text{exp}(\frac{-x²}{2\sigma^{2}}) dx$

Doing change of variable $u = \frac{x}{\sqrt{2}\sigma} \implies du = \frac{dx}{\sqrt{2}\sigma} \implies \sqrt{2}\sigma du = dx$

Then we have

$ B = \sqrt{2}\sigma \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \text{exp}(-u²) du = \sqrt{2} \sigma \sqrt{π}$

Thus $\frac{B}{\sqrt{2π}} = \sigma$

And we are done.